# How do I fix this circular dependency in Python?

Tags: python

I have a circular dependency between two classes in Python. I am not sure how to resolve this circular dependency.

Both classes should be in their own module. At the moment, I am constrained to have both classes in the same module because of the dependency between them.

Example:

- There are two classes which depend on each other. `Scheduler` and `SystemCall`.

```
class Scheduler:

    def run(self):
        while self.task_map:
            task = self.ready_queue.get()
            result = task.run()
            if isinstance(result, SystemCall):
               result.set_task_and_scheduler(task, self)

class SystemCall:
    
    def set_task_and_scheduler(self, task: Task, scheduler: Scheduler) -> None:
        if not is instance(scheduler, Scheduler):
            print(f'scheduler must be of type Scheduler')
```

The `ready_queue` can hold different tasks, some of which are of type `SystemCall`. If a system call is seen, then a function needs to be called to set information about the originating task, and scheduler, which is used as part of a callback mechanism.

With other OOP languages, it is possible to insert a forward declaration of the class to resolve the problem. Python doesn't have a way to do this.

Another way to resolve the problem might be to refactor the code to remove the inter-dependency. But I can't see an easy way to do this.

Comment: It'd help to make a [mre] so that we can try running the code ourselves, but also so that irrelevant factors are removed, like, `task` doesn't seem relevant to the problem.

Comment: "Python doesn't have a way to do this." `def foo(self, task: Task, scheduler: "Scheduler"): ...`

Comment: The `Scheduler` [should be an interface](https://realpython.com/python-interface/) and the one with the `run` method should implement it.

Comment: Could you replace the `if isinstance(result, SystemCall)` with: `if hasattr(result, 'set_task_and_scheduler'):`?

Comment: The runtime type-check seems unnecessary. Let a tool like `mypy` enforce passing `Scheduler` instances as an argument instead.

Comment: Seems like I case to use a [`Protocol`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/), except that protocols can't be used in `isinstance()` (it throws a TypeError), If there is a legitimate concern of an invalid type being passed as a scheduler such that relying on static type checkers is not sufficient, you would have to use a `try/except AttributeErrror` block when calling the method instead of relying on `isinstance()`

Answer (score 5):

You can use an "interface" approach:

```py
# Interface
class Scheduler:
    def run(self):
        pass
```

```py
# Implementing class that references SystemCall
class SchedulerImpl(Scheduler):
    def run(self):
        while self.task_map:
            task = self.ready_queue.get()
            result = task.run()
            if isinstance(result, SystemCall):
               result.set_task_and_scheduler(task, self)
```

```py
# Uses the Scheduler interface
class SystemCall:
    def set_task_and_scheduler(self, task: Task, scheduler: Scheduler) -> None:
        if not is instance(scheduler, Scheduler):
            print(f'scheduler must be of type Scheduler')
```

Comment: Neat design here!

Comment: This is like the [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) from the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles.